# PrimeNG manually invoke FileUpload

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to select the files first and then to start upload those files by an another button instead of component's own `Upload` button.

How can I do this?

**Example code what I've tried:**

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Start Upload"
        (click)="startUpload()"></button>

<p-fileUpload #fileInput name="fileIcon"
              url="rest/batch/file/multimedia/"></p-fileUpload>


@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:ElementRef;

constructor( private renderer: Renderer ) { }

startUpload(){

    // this.fileInput.upload(); -> doesn't compile, undefined
    // this.fileInput.nativeElement.upload(); -> this.fileInput.nativeElement is undefined

    ?????????????????
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Example code which works for me

```
import {FileUpload} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: FileUpload;

    startUpload(){
        this.fileInput.upload();
    }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wNZGM1cNMB0bYhgvXwI0?p=preview)**

Comment: So simple, changing `fileInput:ElementRef` to `fileInput:FileUpload` solved the issue. Thank you..

Comment: it works, however would be nice to submit it with some other parameters via POST

Comment: I can't make this work. I'm getting this message in browser console:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'primeng/primeng' in...
Even changing the path to 'primeng/fileupload/fileupload' doesn't work. Please, any help will be appreciated. I'm declaring the viewchild this  way: @ViewChild(FileUpload, {static: false}) btnUpload: FileUpload;

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you should use build in buttons. To get access to class variables and methods, you can use ViewChild. You should:

1. Set customUpload to true.
2. Set your uploadHandler for custom upload
3. Set local variable #variable_name in template.
4. Add ViewChild with local variable as selector in component.ts
5. Add new variable to your component.ts with FileUpload type (so now you have access to variables and methods - in VS Code you can click right and go to definition to see all things)

   ```
   @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:FileUpload;
   // remember to import FileUpload and of course FileUploadModule

   onSelect() {
     // here custom validation for file (for example check image's dimension)
   }
   customUpload(event) {
     // here you can set your custom upload
   }
   ```