# Cannot set Content-Type in Angular FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, primeng

I have an PrimeNG FileUpload control in my Angular project and I manually invoke upload method as shown on  [PrimeNG manually invoke FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153451/primeng-manually-invoke-fileupload). However, although I have properly fill the files parameter with file data, the data lost its value and returns null after passing from service.ts to Controller (ASP.NET MVC). I think the problem is caused by not being able to set Content-Type in none of the events as shown below:

```
onBeforeSendFile(event: any) {
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
}

or

onBeforeUploadFile(event: any) {
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
}
```

etc...

I encounter "Cannot read property 'setRequestHeader' of undefined" error ath the setRequestHeader lines. Could you please inform me how can I set the necessary RequestHeaders and not lost the file data?

**Update:**
Here is my post method below:

```
 post(url: string, body: any, comp?: BaseComponent): Observable<any> {
    this.requestInterceptor(comp);
    return this.http.post<any>(url, { body: JSON.stringify(body) },
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({  // set the header values here
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Test-Header': 'This is just a test header!'
            })
        }
    ).pipe(
        catchError((error, obs) => this.handleError(error, comp)),
        tap((res: Response) => {
            this.onSubscribeSuccess(res, comp);
        }, (error: any) => {
            this.onSubscribeError(error, comp);
        }),
        finalize(() => {
            this.onFinally(comp);
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient) instead like:

```
this._HttpClient.post('url whatever', { 'body': 'here' }, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({  // set the header values here
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    })
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Although I can pass a custom HttpHeaders (it is observed in Network of Chrome Developer Tool) as shown above (called 'Test-Header') the Content-Type parameter value is not changed and seen as **Content-Type: application/json**. Is it related to JSON.stringify(body) line? Any idea? I think we are so close to the solution ;)

Comment: have you maybe had the luck of solving this? I am experiencing the same issue, seems like I hit the wall :-/